# After onepage checkout how to proceed for selected Payment Method

Tags: magento-1.7

All the required values are stored in session for the checkout outside Magento and now need to know how to redirect to the payment page or place order using code that can be used outside the Magento.

There might be some session action or some direct url that can be used to proceed to place order with the values inside the session.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the Paypal Standard workflow.

The redirect can be found here: `Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect`

Comment: All the data is inside the session like:
addresses
Shipping Method
Payment Method
;;; Now just need a url redirection or similar method that can actively place the order